# How can I deploy hawtio as a servlet inside of a ROOT tomcat webapp

Tags: tomcat, servlets, hawtio

I have a webapp that runs in the ROOT context of a Tomcat6 instance.  I'd like to add a hawtio console to this webapp, accessible via a sub path.  That is, I'd like `http://myserver:8080` to still be my webapp, but `http://myserver:8080/hawtio` to open up the hawtio console.

I'm aware that I can just copy over the `hawtio.war` file to the `$TOMCAT_HOME\webapps` and that'll get me pretty much there.  Alas, I do NOT want to have to deploy two separate webapps but instead just deploy the one, and have hawtio come along for the ride.

I started by adding hawtio as a dependency in my `pom.xml` like so:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.hawt</groupId>
  <artifactId>hawtio-default-offline</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.2</version>
  <type>war</type>
</dependency>
```

Couple that with my assembly scripts and I have a war file that contains all of the necessary hawtio classes.

Next, I need to map the hawtio servlet to my subpath in the `web.xml`.  Maybe like so:

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>HawtioServlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>THIS-IS-MY-QUESTION</servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>3</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>HawtioServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/hawtio/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

And that's where I need my question answered.  What is the hawtio servlet class, that I can use in this case?

I see a bunch of hawtio servlets in the various hawtio packages, but all appear to be sub servlets and not the main one.

What am I missing?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? IMHO better to have hawtio as separated as you can have independent upgrades and whatnot. eg just upgrade your app without upgrading hawtio and vice-versa

Comment: Service deployment is non-trivial in our production environment.  Adding a the dependency to a pom file plus an update to a web.xml file would be far easier and more practical.  This isn't unprecedented, either.  The Jolokia dependency has an agent that works precisely in this manner.  My assumption was that hawtio would have a similar mechanism.

Comment: combining hawtio with your WAR should work - but I'd copy all of hawtio-web's web.xml into your war; there's a fair bit of stuff in there... https://github.com/hawtio/hawtio/blob/master/hawtio-web/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml#L9

Comment: one day, when hawtio goes Servlet 3.0 - we'd use annotations and things would be much easier to combine; the downside is we're trying to make hawtio run everywhere; so we can't assume Servlet 3 any time soon...

Comment: Thanks, James.  Can you post that as an answer to my question so I can accept it.  That is precisely the info I was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

combining hawtio with your WAR should work (providing there's no clashes with JS libraries, CSS, images or HTML files etc).

However the maven-war-plugin doesn't combine web.xml files if you depend on another WAR; so I'd recommend copying the web.xml from hawtio: https://github.com/hawtio/hawtio/blob/master/hawtio-web/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml#L9 and adding your own stuff into it.

One day, when hawtio goes Servlet 3.0 - we'd use annotations and things would be much easier to combine; the downside is we're trying to make hawtio run everywhere; so we can't assume Servlet 3 any time soon